# Sum function doesn't work with pound sign (£)

Tags: google-sheets, sum, currency-formatting

I've been trying to work out a total spend from a list of data - the data is in `£x` format. When I use the sum function on this data range, it always just says '0'.

I've tried formatting it as number, currency, made sure it isn't plain text, everything, and nothing changes it. The only way the sum function works is when I go through the data and individually remove the `£` signs from each cell so that it is just a number.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

This is because the data including `£` is input as a text/string.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(C:C,"£",""))
```

- `SUBSTITUTE` the pound sign to a empty space
- `SUMPRODUCT` to

  - Enforce array context: This substitutes all of C:C instead of just C1. This can be achieved with `ARRAYFORMULA` also.
  - Change the resulting substituted "text" array to "number"  format.
  - `SUM` the resulting substituted array

Comment: Not really sure why the `subproduct` is needed, but it does seem to be. Otherwise you get text, with that, get a number that can then use format or do futher maths with

Comment: ok thanks. I actually used this for converting a single cell (like C3). Using SUBSTITUTE on its own, resulted in the field still being text, and not formattable, Copied your formular, and got a number. But thinking about it *now* its probably the double minus that converts to number. one makes it a negative number, the second converts it back to positive. Could use  =`SUBSTITUTE(...)*1` or =`SUBSTITUTE(...)+0` to same effect

Comment: @barryhunter Yes, the double unary operator `--` does convert. But I originally added it as a insurance in case `SUMPRODUCT` fails. `SUMPRODUCT` in and of itself would do the same conversion in addition to all other effects.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, I had to remove the £ symbol first, then with all the cells needed highlighted go into

Format > Number > More Formats > More currencies

and select British Pound Sterling from the list.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the data is plain text rather than number, so you should have to remove the pound symbol first in order to make the values be recognized as numbers.

You could use Find and Replace to remove all the pound symbols or use a function like [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en) or [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) to remove the pound symbol only for the formulas where it's required.

Another alternative is to use [VALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220?hl=en).